# 3x3 bingo game with a user given input

Tags: c#, game

I implemented a bingo game and check for line, bingo or nothing for a given input where I get a 3x3 bingo card and next 15 numbers extracted.

I wrote the following functions:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const int numberOfRows = 3;
        const int numberOfColumnns = 3;
        const int numbersExtracted = 15;
        int[,] bingoCard = ReadBingoCard(numberOfRows, numberOfColumnns);
        int[] numbers = ReadNumbersExtracted(numbersExtracted);
        PrintResult(bingoCard, numbers);
    }

static int[,] ReadBingoCard(int rowsNumber, int columnNumber)
{
    int[,] card = new int[rowsNumber, columnNumber];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsNumber; i++)
    {
        string[] array = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        for (int j = 0; j < columnNumber; j++)
        {
            card[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(array[j]);
        }
    }

    return card;
}

static int[] ReadNumbersExtracted(int numbersExtracted)
{
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersExtracted];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersExtracted; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    return numbers;
}



  static bool CheckForBingo(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
{
    int numMatchesFound = 0;
    foreach (var number in bingoCard)
    {
        for (int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
        {
            if (number  == numbers[numIndex])
            {
                numMatchesFound++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return numMatchesFound == bingoCard.Length;
}

static bool CheckForLine(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbers)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < bingoCard.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            int colMatchesInRow = 0;

            for (int col = 0; col < bingoCard.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                for(int numIndex = 0; numIndex < numbers.Length; numIndex++)
                {
                    if (bingoCard[row, col] != numbers[numIndex])
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    colMatchesInRow++;
                    break;
                }
            }
 static void PrintResult(int[,] bingoCard, int[] numbersExtracted)
    {
        if (CheckForBingo(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("bingo");
        }
        else if (CheckForLine(bingoCard, numbersExtracted))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("line");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like the `CheckForLine()` function using 3 nested loops.
I can't use Linq, due to Sonar analyzer limitation.

Basiclly I use a 2D user inputed array for the 3x3 bingo card, then i have a function which asks me to input 15 numbers. If all the numbers from the 3x3 bingo card are present in those 15 extracted numbers then I have "bingo". If I have numbers from a line but not all numbers then the program will output "line". And if i will not have bingo neither line the program will output "nothing"

Comment: The code is incomplete. Please paste all your code, including class definition, imports and tell us something about the purpose of those functions and how are they used.

Comment: Take a look. I added the rest of the code.

Comment: Basiclly I use a 2D user inputed array for the 3x3 bingo card, then i have a function which asks me to input 15 numbers. If all the numbers from the  3x3 bingo card are present in those 15 extracted numbers then I have "bingo".  If I have numbers from a line but not all numbers then the program will output "line". And if i will not have bingo neither line the program will output "nothing".

Comment: Much better, just please put the last comment directly into your post. And just one question to be clear - if not bingo, only the horizontal lines are checked, no columns or diagonals, right?

Comment: And one little nitpicky detail, you say "line" or "nothing", but your code spits "linie" or "nimic" - keep those in sync so that people are not confused.

Comment: Hmm actually the CheckForLine function is still incomplete

Comment: I`ve made the edits. Yes, only the horizontal lines. Why you think it's incomplete?

Answer (score 2):

Without comments or a specification, it's hard to tell if this code is correct. `CheckForBingo` seems to check if the entire board is filled, which is not something I remember doing the last time I played Bingo. That particular function could be written in a single line as:

```
return bingoCard.Cast<int>().All(val => numbers.Contains(val));
```

Or in a point-free style:

```
return bingoCard.Cast<int>().All(numbers.Contains);
```

You say you can't use Linq for some reason, but maybe it would be worth adding your own implementation of at least `Contains` since you could use it elsewhere. `CheckForLine` is obviously incomplete, but it's hard to tell if you mean to check columns and diagonals in addition to rows.

Your code seems to support non-square boards, but that seems like more flexibility than is ever needed. It would simplify things a bit to just have a single `boardSize` for both length and width.

`ReadNumbersExtracted` is not a great name, but maybe that's just a language issue. There's a bit of oddness where you pass in the number expected but will read everything that is present, whether it's more or less. If you really expect a fixed amount coming in you should validate that.

Organizationally, the board management code could go into a `Board` class.